# tomcat 7.0 embedded + jax-ws: can not find sun-jaxws.xml

Tags: java, jax-ws, tomcat7

I am trying to have JAX-WS working with embedded tomcat 7.0. 
I followed a few tutorials talking about the standard Tomcat (e.g. http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/ ), but i was not able to find one specific for Tomcat emebedded.

I did succeeded running my own servlets on the server, but when trying to start it with a class containing all JAX-WS annotations (and all the rest : WSServletContextListener + WSServlet in web.xml, sun-jaxws.xml in WEB-INF), i got the following error:

```
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
2 oct. 2012 14:48:20 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
2 oct. 2012 14:48:20 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
2 oct. 2012 14:48:21 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
2 oct. 2012 14:48:28 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12 : initialisation du processus découte de contexte JAX-WS
2 oct. 2012 14:48:28 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11 : fail analyzing descriptor : javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: execution descriptor  "/WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml" is missing
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Le descripteur d'exécution "/WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml" is missing
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:125)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:152)
```

It looks like a path problem, but i do not understand what is missing, since the web.xml in the same folder WEB-INF folder is correctly loaded...
Here is the startup code of my application:
        try {

```
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setBaseDir(".");
        tomcat.setPort(80);

        tomcat.getHost().setAppBase("src/main/webapp");
        Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/Test", ".");
        File configFile = new File(tomcat.getHost().getAppBase() + "/META-INF/context.xml");
        context.setConfigFile(configFile.toURI().toURL());

        tomcat.enableNaming();

        StandardServer server = (StandardServer)tomcat.getServer();
        AprLifecycleListener listener = new AprLifecycleListener();
        server.addLifecycleListener(listener);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks for help or suggestions...

Comment: you got any solution on this ?